# Is a Mac OS machine required to build an IOS app in react native using Expo?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

I'm using a Windows machine. Do I need a Mac OS machine in order to build an iOS app using react native expo eas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. EAS (Expo Application Service) takes care of that for you. Note EAS only allows you 15 free iOS builds per month.

Comment: only 15 free iOS builds per month? do have any link. after 15 builds what to do ?

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari Pricing information is found [here](https://expo.dev/pricing). You can upgrade to a paid plan for $2 per iOS build.